# Javascript Distance Calculator Not Working When Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just having an issue trying to get the distance calculator working on my web page. If you could have a look at the code below and see anything wrong, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

This is my `DistanceCalc.js` File:

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

My inline JS Script:

```
/*----LOCATION FINDER SCRIPT----*/

<script src = "distancecalc.js"></script>
<script>
    function success(position) {
    document.getElementById ('visitus').style.display = 'block';

    document.getElementById ('coordlat').innerHTML =  position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById ('coordlong').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById ('distance2').innerHTML = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(51.897871900000000000, -8.471087399999988000, 
    position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<p>To See Your Distance From <br>Clonakilty, Main Street, Click <button onclick="navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);">Here</button></p>
```

Have never used this type of stuff on my website before so I really don't know how to debug it.

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Your `CSS Script` has nothing to do with CSS. In The HTML, where is `getCurrentPosition` defined?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides The console?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides So you are saying move the script to the HTML document?

Comment: looks just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b04wbv7t/2/

Comment: may be, your script tag is `<script src = "distancecalc.js"></script>`, but the file name given is `DistanceCalc.js` - look at `d` and `D`